# Excel Type mistmach 13

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code.

```
Sub SumZisk()
    Dim suma As Integer

    For i = 1 To 20
        Set curCell = Cells(i, 3)
        suma = suma + curCell.Value
    Next i


    Range("C21").Value = suma


End Sub
```

Error: Type mistmach 13

Thanks for every answers :)

Comment: What line has the error? My guess is that one of the cells in the range doesn't contain an integer, but there is no way to tell for sure since you haven't bothered to say what the range contains. Also -- you really should be using `Option Explicit` rather than using all of these implicitly declared variables.

Comment: @JohnColeman Line number: 7

Comment: @Dortík Your numbering system is ambiguous. To me, Line 7 is the `Next i` line. Also, have you tried our fixes yet? Did they work? In general on SO, you should inform your answerers about what works and doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me. Try using this with `Option Explicit`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SumZisk()

Dim suma As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim curCell As Range

For i = 1 To 20
    Set curCell = Cells(i, 3)
    suma = suma + curCell.Value
Next i

Range("C21").Value = suma


End Sub
```

Comment: While the `Option Explicit` is nice -- this code is probably going to have exactly the same type error in exactly the same line. The problem isn't the code -- it is the in the interaction of the code and the range.

Comment: You were correct about CInt(). I removed my answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right about the `CInt()`. The above code worked for me.

Comment: The question as it stands can't be answered. It is obvious that `curCell.Value` (for at least one `i`) contains a value that can't be converted to an integer -- but OP hasn't given any clue as to what those values look like.

Comment: @JohnColeman I agree with you. My answer assumes that they are all integers or are able to be implicitly converted to such. The OP does need to give more info on the values he has. Thanks!

Comment: Off hand guess: an off-by-one error in which labels are accidentally included in the summation range.